# Command line login failed with two strings ID in Debian Stretch

Tags: login, nologin

I have Debian Stretch and my user name is two strings like "jkl mno" and I when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> command line appears and gui disappears and I can't log in with my credentials, so I created another account with  single string like "avc" and when I supply its password and user ID it logs in. How can I fix the problem of not bing able to log in with user ID of two strings. (there is a space in one word jkl and the other mno).

I can easily log in with GUI however.

Answer (score 4):

User names aren’t supposed to contain the space character; POSIX [recommends](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_437) only using characters from the [portable filename character set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282), which contains all unaccented US English alphanumerics, period, underscore, and hyphen. Additional allowable characters which aren’t part of the portable filename character set are the at-sign (‘@’) and the dollar symbol (‘$’, for compability with Samba).

It’s not surprising that you can’t log in using “jkl mno”. You should switch to a user name without a space character (you can do this by editing `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, and `/etc/group`).

Note that on Debian and derivatives, the user creation tool, `adduser`, enforces these restrictions by default.

Comment: Thank you Stephen King, I misspoke earlier, it was not my user name which had two strings, my ID as I do "whoami" is one string, however, the name which I see in GUI mode when I start the Linux is two string, that is my full name.
However, I created another account with adduser and the name is just one string and it works fine.

I don't know what to edit in /etc/shadow or /etc/group as with name (single string username) there is a long string of Lord knows what meaning.

Comment: @Jawad then you shouldn’t have any problems; you need to use your short id to log in, that’s all. Full names can contain spaces.

Comment: Actually I can do that, thank you @Stephen King, using the one word userID/user name however I wanted to login with my first ID as well.

Is there a way to change/reset my userID, which has two words in it, without loosing functionality of other programs/software as I may not be able to login to a database managed software like Oracle.

In fact I would like all easy methods, just warn me if a method will cast me to lose functionality of other programs.

Thank you

Comment: Your two comments here contradict each other. Does your id contain a space, or doesn’t it?