# How do I make this script search through all users home folders and then rm -f the files matching EXT?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, rm

How do I make this script search through all users' home folders and then `rm -f` the files matching EXT? Right now it's only deleting the files matching EXT in the current folder where I am executing the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
EXT=jpg
for i in *; do
  if [ "${i}" != "${i%.${EXT}}" ];then
    echo "I do something with the file $i"
    rm -f $i
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use bash's [globstar option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) to recurse for you:

```
EXT=csv             ## for example
shopt -s globstar failglob
rm -f /home/**/*."$EXT"
```

(Assuming all your user's home directories are under /home). I've also set `failglob` so that if there are no matching files, the `rm` command is not run.

More generally, you could pull up your user's home directories with a shell loop:

```
shopt -s globstar failglob
for homedir in $(getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 >= 500 { print $6 }'|sort -u)
do
  rm -f "$homedir"/**/*."$EXT"
done
```

This runs on the **assumption** that you don't have any user home directories with spaces, tabs, or newlines in them.

Comment: Thanks! How would that fit into the first script I posted above?

Comment: I would consider replacing it, depending on what extensions you're interested in -- you could loop over them as well.

Comment: @JeffSchaller [According to this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401782/265604), usernames should not contain spaces.

Comment: @isaac It wouldn’t be the usernames, as I’m printing the home directories. I’ve never seen a home directory with a space in it, but it’s possible.

Comment: They're anywhere the administrator wants them to be. The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#HOMEUSERHOMEDIRECTORIES) says: "/home is a fairly standard concept, but it is clearly a site-specific filesystem. [9] The setup will differ from host to host. Therefore, no program should rely on this location. [10]"

Comment: Agreed that `username` may not have spaces, but `/ho me/` (or its substitute) might.

Answer (score 0):

To test:

`find /home/ -name '*.txt' -exec ls -l {} \;`

To actually remove:

`find /home/ -name '*.txt' -exec rm -f {} \;`

Of course replace 'txt' with what you need.