# How to install an application from archlinux.org

Tags: arch-linux, aur

I am trying to download IntelliJ IDEA application from the AUR.

I can see that is on archlinux.org [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition). However when I type in `sudo pacman -S intellij-idea-ultimate-edition` I get error `target not found : intellij-idea-ultimate-edition`

How do I install this package from AUR? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an [AUR helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AUR_helpers). Personally, I use [`trizen`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/trizen), but you can find a list of available [AUR helpers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AUR_helpers#Pacman_wrappers) here. As usual, Arch has excellent documentation on this. The helper itself will probably need to be installed manually from source, but once you have done that, you can use it the same way (or even instead of, if you choose a `pacman` wrapper like `trizen`) as `pacman`. For example, to install `intellij-idea-ultimate-edition` using `trizen`, I would do:

```
trizen -S intellij-idea-ultimate-edition
```

If you are 100% sure about the package (not always a good idea with AUR packages), you can even tell `trizen` not to prompt you and answer all prompts with yes:

```
trizen -S --noconfirm intellij-idea-ultimate-edition
```

Everything else works just like `pacman`. For instance, you can upgrade everything on the system (both regular and AUR packages) with

```
trizen -Suy
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148517/discussion-on-answer-by-terdon-how-to-install-an-application-from-archlinux-org); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I have `git config --global url.https://aur.archlinux.org/.insteadof aur:` set up, and build my aur-sourced packages under my `~/aur` directory, so for me,

```
$ cd ~/aur
$ git clone aur:intellij-idea-ultimate-edition
$ cd intellij-idea-ultimate-edition    # or ${_:4}, retype the name howsomever
$ makepkg -si
```

was all it took. There's AUR helpers for automatically hunting down dependencies that are themselves AUR packages and installing them with --asdeps and such, I don't use enough AUR packages to make bothering with one worthwhile and it's completely unnecessary here.

Comment: Nice, but the classic caveats about parsing `ls` apply. With recent versions of GNU `ls` you could make it significantly better by using `cd "$(ls -t --zero | head -z -n1)"`.

Comment: @terdon I hear you, and the caveats are worth mentioning, but they *don't* apply here. Git repo names are served from urls, urls with embedded white space are such a pain nobody uses them.

Comment: Famous last words :) I mean yeah, I know, the risk here is indeed minimal, but since the newer `ls` can do this and this [mitigates the risk almost entirely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/754193/22222) for no significant overhead, it seems a shame not to use it.

Comment: Or you can use `cd "${_:4}"` to avoid all that ;-).

Comment: Package names can contain only alphanumeric characters and any of `@`, `.`, `_`, `+`, `-`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan to use an AUR helper, you can simply build the package from source by running(using the package you gave here as an example):

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition
cd intellj-idea-ultimate-edition
makepkg
pacman -U intellij-idea-ultimate-edition-2023.2.1-x86_84.pkg.tar.zst
```

If you *do* want an AUR helper, I'd highly recommend [aurutils](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/aurutils), as it integrates directly with pacman, instead of trying to just act like pacman.

After you've installed it, Aurutils requires you to setup a local repo, and they have instructions for this and more advanced usuage in the bundled [man pages](https://github.com/AladW/aurutils/blob/master/man1/aur.1)
but the basics of it are: 
Add this to the bottom of /etc/pacman.conf 
(the local repository root is /home/custompkgs here but you can keep it in any dir you want to)

```
[custom]
    SigLevel = Optional TrustAll
    Server = file:///home/custompkgs
```

Create the repo root and database:

```
sudo install -d /home/custompkgs -o $USER
repo -add /home/custompkgs/custom.db.tar.gz
```

If there are any built packages, add them to the database:

```
cd /home/custompkgs
repo -add -n custom.db.tar.gz *.pkg.tar*
```

And then sync pacman by running `sudo pacman -Syu`
To install packages with aurutils, just run `aur sync {name of package}` and then `pacman -S {name of package}`

Answer (score -1):

As any other AUR package (you even tagged [aur](/questions/tagged/aur), so I'll assume you'll know what that means), as documented on https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_User_Repository :

1. Get the PGP key
2. get the AUR source files by cloning the appropriate `https://aur.archlinux.org/{…}.git`; check the PGP signature
3. do the build using `makepkg` in the directory you just cloned. As usual on arch, you need to remember the flags that everyone always needs to use, iirc these are `makepkg -s -r -c`. And if you're doing a new build, you'd still want to `git clean -xdf`, because this is very mature, very clean and very reliable package building…
4. install the package you just built using `pacman -U ….pkg.tar.zst`

I cannot stress enough how finicky all this is. If you run an update of your system (which you basically need to do every time you install a new package), the dependencies of your self-built package might (will!) break, and you need to do a fresh build. But you won't hear about that from pacman; things just… break.